# DateTime.ParseExact issue with non-standard timezone string

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm talking to web service that is returning me a date in this format
`Fri, 02 Oct 2009 05:33:11 - 0500`

I've been trying to parse it into a `DateTime` in C# and get an invalid string error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Here is the code:

```
string text = "Fri, 02 Oct 2009 05:33:11 - 0500";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text,"ddd, dd MMM yyyy h:mm:ss - zzzzz", null);
```

If I remove the  `- 0500` and the  `- zzzz` from the `ParseExact` argument, it works just fine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong on the timezone though. Any direction would be appreciated. I've tried different counts of the "z" and removing the "-" also assuming it was confusing that for negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply, *can't*.

Your input is not a valid string which can parsed to `DateTime` *unless* you do some string manipulation in it. And your offset part **must** have semi colon (`:`) to parse it.

Also you need to use [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) (or preferable [`HH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier)) since your hour part has a leading zero.

I can only think one way, get the last index of white space, remove it, insert `:` between your hours and minutes of offset, and parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) since your string has [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) part.

```
string text = "Fri, 02 Oct 2009 05:33:11 -05:00";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(text, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `2.10.2009 05:33:11 -05:00` and you can use it's `DateTime`, `LocalDateTime` or `UtcDateTime` properties.

Comment: +1 Worked for me in Linqpad: DateTime dt = dto.DateTime;
dt.Dump(); returns `02.10.2009 05:33:11`